# How to get the root record in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, tree, recursive-query, hierarchical-query

Starting from the generic node (or leaf) how to get the root node?

```
SELECT 
    ID,MSG_ID,PARENT_ID 
FROM 
    TABLE_X
CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ID = ID;

ID  MSG_ID                              PARENT_ID
4   3                                   NULL
5   93bea0f71b07-4037-9009-f148fa39bb62 4
4   3                                   NULL
6   6f5f5d4ab1ec-4f00-8448-7a6dfa6461b2 4
4   3                                   NULL    
7   3                                   NULL
8   7e0fae569637-4d29-9075-c273eb39ae8e 7
7   3                                   NULL
9   8a3e7485b3e8-45b1-a31d-c52fd32111c0 7
7   3                                   NULL
10  fcc622d5af92-4e61-8d7c-add3da359a8b 7
7   3                                   NULL
```

How to get the root msg_id?

Comment: Am I reading this right? There are two roots, and the `msg_id` for both is just `'3'`?

Comment: Yes in the db i can have two roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right path, but you are missing two essential ingredients.

First, to indicate the starting point, you need to use the `start with` clause. Obviously, it will be something like `start with id = <input value>`. You didn't tell us how you will provide the input value. The most common approach is to use bind variables (best for many reasons); I named the bind variable `input_id` in the query below.

Second, you only want the "last" row (since you are navigating the tree in the opposite direction: towards the root, not from the root; so the root is now the "leaf" as you navigate this way). For that you can use the `connect_by_isleaf` pseudocolumn in the `where` clause.

So, the query should look like this: (note that I am only selecting the root message id, as that is all you requested; if you need more columns, include them in `select`)

```
select  msg_id
from    table_x
where   connect_by_isleaf = 1  -- keep just the root row (leaf in this traversal)
start   with id = :input_id    -- to give the starting node
connect by prior parent_id = id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with cte (id, msg_id, parent_id) as (
    select id, msg_id, parent_id, from mytable where id = ?
    union all
    select t.id, t.msg_id, t.parent_id
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.parent_id = t.id
)
select * from cte where parent_id is null
```

Comment: There is no need to scan `cte` a second time - and there is no need for `lvl`. The `where` clause should be `where parent_id is null`.